# I am getting such an error while publishing, I could not analyze?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core

> CSC : warning AD0001: Analyzer 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.TopLevelParameterNameAnalyzer' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' with message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.

The problem is as follows, I'm going to publish and get the project live, it works locally, but when publishing, it doesn't work with this error code and I tried the solutions I looked at, but the problem did not improve.

Layers netstandard2.1 UI Layer .net 5.0

Comment: this error means something in your code is not getting any value, and you need to find that somehow.
have you tried debugging?  because this will help

Comment: Have you migrated the project? You can read this article, the situation is similar to yours: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14723

Comment: Did you try disabling the code analyzer as described here? https://intelequia.com/blog/post/2584/workaround-ad0001-analyzer-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-analyzers-toplevelparameternameanalyzer-threw-an-exception what happened?